# Inline onchange script to external JS

Tags: javascript, inline, external

I have a form selector element, which has an inline script following onchange:

```
<select onchange="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
     <option value="select">Select color</option>
     <option class="greenOpt" value="green" >Green</option>
    <option class="yellowOpt"   value="yellow" >Yellow</option>
    <option class="blueOpt" value="blue" >Blue</option>
</select>
```

This works perfectly for my output, changing the background color of the options the same color as their word, Green is green, Yellow is yellow, etc.

```
.greenOpt{
background-color: green;
text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
}

.blueOpt{
  background-color: blue;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  }

.yellowOpt{
  background-color: yellow;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
}
```

But I want to move that `onchange` script into an external function and I am unsure of how that should look.  I understand what I need to do in the `<select>` tag, is `onchange="colorSel()"`

My function so far:

```
function colorSel() {
  var colors = document.getElementById("colors");
  colors = this.className = this.options[this.selectedIndex].className;
  }
```

I am stumped.  I have changed the parameter the of the function and the getElement type to many different things.  I just don't get it.

Comment: Why are you assigning colors with the className? In your original inline method, you are not doing this.

Comment: That was not what I meant to be there....

Comment: I forgot to press enter to move the function name into the code block.

Comment: @Abraxes - I have posted a solution to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not provided the code for the colors element, so I have demonstrated something with what you have given:

```js
change = function(selectObject) {
   selectObject.className= selectObject.options[selectObject.selectedIndex].className
}
```

```css
.greenSel{
  background-color: green;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
}

.blueSel{
  background-color: blue;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
  }

.yellowSel{
  background-color: yellow;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 white, 0 1px white, 1px 0 white, 0 -1px white;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="change(this)">
    <option value="select">Select color</option>
    <option class="greenSel" value="green" >Green</option>
    <option class="yellowSel"   value="yellow" >Yellow</option>
    <option class="blueSel" value="blue" >Blue</option>
</select>
```

You missed passing in this to your onchange method and grabbing the value from the selected choice.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, however this is not the intended outcome.  I am trying to get the option selected, to change color.  So where it says Apple now, the background in the options selector is green.

Comment: The "color" element is the select!

Comment: @Abraxas - I still don't understand what you want. You have css classes already attached to the selected items. What are they for? What would you like to happen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Abraxxas/u1mqgcyf/58/

When you select an option, the color of the background of the option matches the words.  So not an output of words matching the color, but the background of the selected option in the selector box.

So I want to figure out how to instead call a function with onchange in the `select` tag, and put that function in my external JS file.

Comment: @Abraxas - I have updated my answer per your comment.

Comment: Wow, that looks nothing like what I had to begin with.  Need to explore this more.

Comment: Also, I removed the `var color` line and the function still works.

Comment: @Abraxas, the colors variable is not necessary. I left it there for you, so you won't say that it is not what you were expecting. Isn't the result what you wanted?

Comment: You didn't need to leave it there.  I was pretty sure color was the wrong track the whole time.  I just didn't know how to make the function valid.  Thank you this is what I was trying to find.

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach a handler for the change event

`document.getElementById("colors").addEventListener('change', function (){
//Your logic goes here
});`